# Js JSON - ошибка SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position

Tags: javascript, json

Ребята подскажите  , получаю с сервера JSON -не могу его распарсить - дает ошибку:

> VM1031:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position
>   0(… )

Код:

```
$('#enter_usrer').click(function(){
  var email=$('#enter_email').val();
  var pass=$('#pass_enter').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/index.php/article/EnterUser',
    type: 'post',
    data: {'email': email , 'pass': pass },
    success: function (data) {
      var event = JSON.parse(data);

      console.log(data);

      if (event.success == 1) {
        $('#ENTER_CHIP').text('Такой Емаил не зарегестрирован');
        $('#ENTER_CHIP').css("display", "block");
      } else {
        if (event.success == 2) {
          $('#ENTER_CHIP').text('Неправельно введен пароль');
          $('#ENTER_CHIP').css("display", "block");
        } else {
          document.location = '/index.php/article/My_cart';
        }
      }

    }
  });

});
```

Comment: попробуйте убрать `var event = JSON.parse(data);`, data - Это уже объект js (не JSON-строка)

Comment: посмотрите в отладчике что у вас там в data приходит и закиньте в jsonlint

Comment: что выведено в консоль вызовом  `console.log(data);`?

Comment: EnterUser{"success":3}  это из консоли

Comment: а должно быть  `{"success":3}`

Comment: Я знаю - не пойму почему присылает  
EnterUser{"success":3}

Comment: посмотри что на самом деле приходит в data

Comment: @Виктор, если сервер на php, то скорее всего нужно использовать функцию json_encode, если не php, То аналогичную функцию

Comment: приходит EnterUser{"success":3}

Comment: в ajax запросе добавьте dataType: 'json', и тогда ответ будет приходить в json формате сразу

Comment: @Виктор, если в коде success присваивается только true или false, откуда появился `{"success":3}`?

Comment: Почему только  true или false - это просто переменная JSON ее значение может быть любого типа - в данном случае я возвращаю код ответа , dataType: 'json' тоже не помогло $s=Users::CheckingAccountById($user_email);}
  if($s==1){echo json_encode(['success'=>true]);}else{json_encode(['success'=>false]);};

Comment: @Виктор, я к тому, что раз возвращается `3` - значит надо искать кусок это 3 присваивается, скорее всего где-то рядом идет какой-нибудь `echo user`

Comment: ДРУЗЬЯ!! Спасибо большое!!!!!! Большое СПАСИБО 0 Гранди был прав _ я в бефорэкшене вывел имя пользователь почему то это сыграло свою роль !! Еще раз всем огромное СПАСИБО!!!

Comment: @Виктор стоит либо написать свой ответ, с пояснениями в чем ошибка и как решал. Либо удалить вопрос, так как проблема на сервере,а в вопросе информация только про клиентскую часть, которая особо к проблеме не относится.

Comment: Хорошо , Еще раз спасибо ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина была в том что: я уже выводил в этом контролере на экран - поэтому он не могу вернуть JSON